# How to fix a div below the header after scrolling it up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header and a banner below it. Below this banner I have my content. So when i scroll the banner should go away(in my case I have increased z index of header so banner basically hides behind it) and when you scroll the content should come up to merge with the header . So i was able to do this with little CSS.

Now when my content div merges with the header I want it to stick there  and then the entire page should scroll up together.

Current CSS to Scroll

```
#header {
    height: 100px;
    background: #bdbdbd;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    background: #707070;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 400px;
    background: #ebebeb;
    height: 1500px; /* Demo purposes */
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: will you be kind enough to show us what you did so far ? code please

Comment: please share some piece of code that you have tried.

Comment: Share the html css javascript code !

Comment: sure i am adding the code

Comment: Make that div position: fixed after certain top get exceeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    height: 100px;
    background: #bdbdbd;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    top:0px;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:100px;
    background: #ebebeb;
}
#banner {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #707070;
}

#banner.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
body {
    margin: 1em;
}
p {
    margin: 1em auto;
}
</style>
```

Here is body:

```
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
<div id="header">This is header</div>

<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque,
    lectus in pharetra blandit, augue mauris pulvinar erat, ut euismod nibh
    lectus sed diam. Nulla fringilla ultrices ligula. Aliquam vitae felis metus.
    Maecenas lacinia bibendum accumsan. Curabitur lobortis convallis purus
    non imperdiet. Morbi ut vulputate mauris. Curabitur lacinia faucibus volutpat.
    Nulla elit tortor, rhoncus ut luctus eget, blandit in risus. Integer accumsan
    ullamcorper lorem id porttitor. Aliquam vitae libero eget magna mollis
    gravida.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
    tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
    justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
    arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
    orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
    morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
    sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
    neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
    mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
    quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
    accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
    ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
    Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
    Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
    molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
    porttitor suscipit.</p>

<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="banner">This will stay at top of page</div>

<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
    nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
    Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
    tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
    velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
    imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
    Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
    id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
    ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
    Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
    enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
    tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
    justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
    arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
    orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
    morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
    sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
    neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
    mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
    quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
    accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
    ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
    Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
    Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
    molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
    porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
    nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
    Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
    tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
    velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
    imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
    Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
    id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
    ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
    Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
    enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>
<p>Nunc eu sapien turpis. Proin non arcu orci, eget volutpat tellus. Maecenas
    tempor mattis risus, quis pellentesque eros imperdiet nec. Vestibulum porttitor,
    justo at ornare bibendum, magna lectus cursus felis, tristique consectetur
    arcu justo at augue. Mauris ultrices mollis sem eget elementum. Sed ipsum
    orci, tempus vel porttitor vel, tristique eu erat. Pellentesque habitant
    morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    Duis aliquam pulvinar nisl, vitae congue velit ultricies eget.</p>
<p>Maecenas mollis arcu orci. Nam nec velit dolor, ut convallis augue. Morbi
    sed massa nunc. Vestibulum malesuada eros sed purus volutpat nec bibendum
    neque sodales. Nullam tincidunt quam sit amet lacus egestas vitae ultrices
    mauris porta. Duis vel neque ipsum. Vestibulum eu blandit ante. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis leo, hendrerit
    quis elementum tincidunt, auctor ac augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Sed in eleifend magna. Morbi faucibus eleifend nunc eu sagittis. Curabitur
    accumsan nulla in neque tempor eu lacinia elit consectetur. Nullam scelerisque
    ligula vitae nisi interdum pellentesque. Vivamus lobortis tempor pulvinar.
    Nunc sit amet nulla urna. Phasellus malesuada euismod lectus nec bibendum.
    Ut adipiscing dapibus ipsum nec iaculis. Donec quis dignissim tortor. Suspendisse
    molestie rhoncus enim hendrerit ultricies. Proin semper purus posuere urna
    porttitor suscipit.</p>
<p>Curabitur odio dui, imperdiet sed sodales nec, aliquet id nisl. Mauris
    nec sapien nibh. Maecenas vel sem at felis posuere rutrum non non mauris.
    Maecenas at lectus ut ipsum iaculis lobortis. Vivamus ut porta nisi. Phasellus
    tempor accumsan urna eu faucibus. Duis sed ligula neque, pulvinar euismod
    velit. Donec tristique eros at dolor ornare sagittis. Vestibulum sodales
    imperdiet ante et tincidunt. Suspendisse malesuada tempor nisi ac accumsan.
    Pellentesque accumsan pulvinar odio, id adipiscing diam mollis eu. Nulla
    id mi rutrum elit rutrum ultrices. Maecenas viverra, est ut pellentesque
    ultricies, ligula nisi auctor tellus, vitae bibendum mi nunc non libero.
    Mauris in facilisis enim. Proin facilisis, risus et tempus accumsan, orci
    enim egestas arcu, sit amet sodales risus leo quis nisi.</p>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top-100;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#banner').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('#banner').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
</script>   
</body>
```